# Auto updates of Google Chrome on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7

We don't want to automatically update Chrome.

How do we disable automatic updates of Google Chrome on Windows 7?

Comment: This can be done with the Chrome Administrator group policy templates. Do you have those installed?